# Python script call other Python scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to make a script that calls every .py file in a specific directory, allowing the called script to access information (classes, variables, etc.) about the calling script.

So I have something like this:

mainfile.py:

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myVar = "a variable"

        for f in os.listdir(path):
            if f.endswith(".py"):
                execfile(path+f)

    def callMe(self):
        print self.myVar

myMain = MainClass()
myMain.callMe()
```

And I want to be able to do the following in callee.py

```
myMain.callMe()
```

Comment: I am curious why aren't you using import and then create instances from those files?

Comment: @WissamYoussef - I need the main script to be the main program. The other scripts are like plugins. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you coming from Java?

Comment: just use import then. no need for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `os.sytem`

```
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if f.endswith(".py"):
        os.system(path+f)
```